# Select rows in Datagridview execute stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, datagridview

Not sure why I am getting this wrong.

Trying to select rows in a datagridview and pass them to a stored procedure.  Every time I execute the following, the correct number of rows are passed but instead of row 4 for instance, it will execute the query on row 1. Or if I selected 2. How do I pass the selected rows to the query and not just the number rows selected?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("uspSelectWater", con);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseNumberKey", this._CaseNum);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterAccount", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaterAccount", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerName", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MailName", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcctBalance", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You don't need that inner loop. A Row has an Index property — you would have to use that.  Otherwise, it's just `r.Cells[3].Value`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already looping your selected rows, so shouldn't need the inner loop.

Just use the selected row

Try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{    

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("uspSelectWater", con);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseNumberKey", this._CaseNum);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterAccount", r.Cells[3].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaterAccount", r.Cells[4].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerName", r.Cells[5].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MailName", r.Cells[6].Value);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcctBalance", r.Cells[7].Value);

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to read the value and then pass to stored procedure:

```
int i;
i = dg.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
str1= dg.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
str2= dg.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```